# Obtener si un usuario es miembro de una organizacion github

Tags: api, git, github

Buenas tardes, para aquellos experimentados en GitHub API tengo una pregunta.

Estoy desarrollando una app en la que quiero hacer un login with github, pero es necesario que para poder ingresar este usuario debe ser parte de nuestra organizacion, la consulta es. A que endpoint de la api debo pegar y con que informacion para poder obtener esto?

Lei por ahi que de esta forma se deberia poder ver si el usuario es miembro de la org.

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/memberships/:user/
```

Pero intente usarla y me pide autenticacion, intente pasarle un acces_token del usuario y un token personal pero no funciono, sigue sin permitirme ver esa info.

Alguien sabe cual es la forma de hacer esto?

Comment: de casualidad hermano, ya has visto la documentación oficial de GitHub?

Comment: Si pero no comprendo esa parte, si tienes algun enlace que pueda ayudarme te agradezco

Comment: Primero habilita el login con github de la manera más básica. Cuando los usuarios inicien sesión en github via tu app, recibirás de vuelta sus datos, incluyendo sus organizaciones. Ahí podrás decirle: lo sentimos, uds no pertenece a la organización, vamos a redirigirlo al index.

Comment: Si, pero no te muestra la org te muestra una url de sus orgs y cuando intento ingresar ahi con el acces token y todo me tira not found